# how mount a TIB (acronis true image file backup) which contains encrypted SYSTEM drive as physical drive, for mount it in True Crypt?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, backup, encryption, truecrypt

***Windows***

how to mount a .TIB  (acronis true image file backup) which contains encrypted **SYSTEM drive** (with partiion 1(100mbsize) and 2(1tb) ) as physical drive, for mount it in True Crypt? and get some files?

I tried OSFMount for mount image (for testing purposes at first) as physidcal drive, but True Crypt dont show it in list partitions/disk after pressing "select device/partition" botton.

Shold I need make 1.1tb empty image for mount in OSFMount and afer Unpack whole drive using Acronis whole drive recovery to this empty image file? After that I need mount this image as drive and mount it in TC? But I have problem with disk drives/partitions listing in true crypt :-(

Any help?

Comment: Was it really encrypted with TrueCrypt? If it was you should have moved to VeraCrypt many years ago. TC is abandoned.

Comment: yes , with TC, Vera Crypt can see virtual drives? Also VC dont have any security audit?

Comment: VC can do everything TC did and yes, it's open-source therefore it's audited all the time. It already contains corrections for TC's vulnerabilities discovered *after* it has been abandoned. Insisting in using TC is just dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved it using virtual machine, unpacking TIB backup in freshly created virtual disk, after select it in TC

Comment: Good to know this worked without needing a spare physical disk. Thanks for posting the solution.

Answer (score 1):

> how to mount a .TIB (acronis true image file backup) which contains encrypted SYSTEM drive (with partiion 1(100mbsize) and 2(1tb) ) as physical drive, for mount it in True Crypt? and get some files?

1) Restore your TIB image to a spare physical drive.

2) TrueCrypt should now be able to recognize and access the encrypted system partition with no difficulty.

Comment: I dont have empty drive for this purpose, maybe use virtual machine for this?

Comment: You can try that and see if it works.